# Detecting Android Go phones

Tags: android, permissions, android-go

I have developed an application but now I would like to check at the first startup of the app if it is an Android Go phone and if so, inform the user that it is not supported.

In Android it is possible to check the SDK version but is it also possible to check if it is a Go phone?

I would like to exclude Android Go phones because they do not support `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` which my app needs.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196665/how-to-detect-check-or-identify-app-is-running-on-android-go-edition-8-1-device

Comment: Maybe my answer will help you. I've posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66579673/4675299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking on the official documentation https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks, it says that for an app to run on android Go, you need to

> To target devices running Android (Go edition), your APK needs to
>   declare:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.ram.low" android:required="true">
```

> target at least API Level 26, and have a higher version code than your non-Go edition APK.

so by simply not putting the previous code in your manifest, your app will not be available for android Go.

Comment: Not sure that this answer is correct. If you simply don't put the code above in your manifest, your app will be available to **both** Go **and** non-Go edition devices.
If you put the code above in  your manifest, your app will be available **only** to Go edition devices.

Answer (score 1):

You could call either

```
 ActivityManager.isLowRamDevice();
```

or

```
PackageManager.hasSystemFeature("FEATURE_RAM_LOW");
```

Both will return `true` if the device is running Android Go edition, and `false` if it's running the regular Android.

[source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#FEATURE_RAM_LOW)

Comment: I think that this answer is the correct one for the question posted.